# firewire audio interface increases glfwSwapBuffers time to complete

Tags: opengl, audio, openframeworks

I'm using openframeworks to make this application, if I connect the firewire echo audiofire 2 interface then the time it takes for glfwSwapBuffers changes from between 200 - 12000 microseconds to a fairly consistent 30000, which ruins the target 60fps.

I've tried commenting out all rendered objects and calling no audio in case the problem was elsewhere. The problem  isn't just slow framerate, occaisionally I will get a very bad flickering covering the lower half of my screen (not just wihin my application but the screen itself).

I'm using MAc OSX 10

Openframeworks uses openGL, here's the function that calls glfwSwapBuffers.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------
void ofAppGLFWWindow::display(void){

ofPtr<ofGLProgrammableRenderer> renderer = ofGetGLProgrammableRenderer();
if(renderer){
    renderer->startRender();
}

// set viewport, clear the screen
ofViewport();       // used to be glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
float * bgPtr = ofBgColorPtr();
bool bClearAuto = ofbClearBg();

// to do non auto clear on PC for now - we do something like "single" buffering --
// it's not that pretty but it work for the most part

#ifdef TARGET_WIN32
if (bClearAuto == false){
    glDrawBuffer (GL_FRONT);
}
#endif

if ( bClearAuto == true ){
    ofClear(bgPtr[0]*255,bgPtr[1]*255,bgPtr[2]*255, bgPtr[3]*255);
}

if( bEnableSetupScreen )ofSetupScreen();

ofNotifyDraw();

#ifdef TARGET_WIN32
if (bClearAuto == false){
    // on a PC resizing a window with this method of accumulation (essentially single buffering)
    // is BAD, so we clear on resize events.
    if (nFramesSinceWindowResized < 3){
        ofClear(bgPtr[0]*255,bgPtr[1]*255,bgPtr[2]*255, bgPtr[3]*255);
    } else {
        if ( (ofGetFrameNum() < 3 || nFramesSinceWindowResized < 3) && bDoubleBuffered)    glfwSwapBuffers(windowP);
        else                                                     glFlush();
    }
} else {
    if(bDoubleBuffered){
        glfwSwapBuffers(windowP);
    } else {
        glFlush();
    }
}
#else
    if (bClearAuto == false)
    {
        // in accum mode resizing a window is BAD, so we clear on resize events.
        if (nFramesSinceWindowResized < 3){
            ofClear(bgPtr[0]*255,bgPtr[1]*255,bgPtr[2]*255, bgPtr[3]*255);
        }
    }

    if(bDoubleBuffered)
    {
        unsigned long long timeStartDisplay = ofGetElapsedTimeMicros();
        glfwSwapBuffers(windowP);
        unsigned long long timeEndDisplay = ofGetElapsedTimeMicros();
        printf("displayTimeAppWindow %llu \n", (timeEndDisplay - timeStartDisplay));
    }
    else
    {
        glFlush();
    }
#endif

if(renderer){
    renderer->finishRender();
}

nFramesSinceWindowResized++;
glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: After much investigation I discovered that if the open gl window is less than 560px by 780px, the problem just goes away. it doesn't progressively get better or worse, there is a definite trigger point. sometimes moving the window or giving the focus back to the window from somewhere else will temporarily make it work as expected. Sometimes it's just one of the two buffers that takes 30000 microseconds.